# ionic 2 Loading is not centered

Tags: ionic2

The example code for the ionic 2 Loading feature that is shown in their docs is:

```js
let loading = Loading.create({
    content: 'Please wait...'
});

this.nav.present(loading);
```

Their online example shows the loading spinner appearing in the centre of the screen but when I try it in my app it appears in the top left hand corner.

How do they get it to appear in the centre?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the latest CSS/Sass in place?

The following works fine for me:

```
import {Loading} from "ionic-angular"

// put this inside a method
let loading = Loading.create({
  content: 'Please wait...'
});
this.nav.present(loading);
```

See a working example here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HzuzbF9sFVEKRsBrnIVI?p=preview

Look at home.ts for the code.

Comment: Where would I get the latest css etc. ?

Comment: Ok I have found the problem. There was an error in one of the scss files that was having a knock on effect!

Comment: Thanks Dan for taking a look at this. Very much appreciated.